# Custom post types and child theme

Tags: custom-post-types, themes, child-theme

Okay, here's the deal. I am working with a child theme and I want a custom post type.

### What I did

Added the following code the `functions.php` of the parent theme.

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_fb_foto_post_type' );
function create_fb_foto_post_type() {
    register_post_type('fotos',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => __( 'Foto\'s' ),
                'singular_name' => __( 'Foto' )
            ),
        'public' => true,
        'has_archive' => true,
        'taxonomies' => array('post_tag')
        )
    );
}
```

Created a template file `single-fotos.php` which contains this code:

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

        <div id="primary" class="site-content">
            <div id="content" role="main">

                <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>

                    <?php get_template_part( 'content', 'page' ); ?>

                    <?php comments_template( '', true ); ?>

                <?php endwhile; // end of the loop. ?>

            </div><!-- #content -->
        </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

And uploaded it to the child theme's directory.

### What goes wrong

I can choose to create a new 'Foto' page when I'm in Wordpress and it contains the tag field. But! When I want to view an example, Wordpress does nothing. When I choose to submit and publish the page it works but when I then want to view it, I get a 404.

### What I tried

I tried uploading the template to the parent theme's directory (after I had created the page) but this doesn't work either.

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have refreshed the permalinks after to include your custom post type?

Comment: @bueltge I created new posts but it happens all the time so I don't think a refresh would help?

Comment: @BramVanroy yes, refresh should help. WordPress needs to generate new rewrite rules for your custom post type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to flush and regenerate your permalinks everytime you modify/add/remove custom post types or taxonomies.

Going to the permalinks page and saving should be enough

( Also your custom post type code should be in a plugin, not the theme, else the user is stuck using that theme forever )